# target.extend(mixin) is not working in magento2.4

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.4

target.extend(mixin) is not working in my code.
I tried multiple changes but those are not working

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function($, ui, ko, stepNavigator){
    'use strict';
    var mixin = {
        isVisibleShippingButton: function () {
            return !stepNavigator.getActiveItemIndex();
        },
        
        isVisiblePaymentButton: function () {
            return stepNavigator.getActiveItemIndex();
        },

        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            
            $(function() {
                $('body').on('click', '#continue-to-payment-trigger', function () {
                    $('#shipping-method-buttons-container').find('.action.continue.primary').trigger('click');
                });                     
                $('body').on('click', '#place-order-trigger', function () {
                    $('.payment-method._active').find('.action.primary.checkout').trigger('click');
                });
            });

            this._super();
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

[image]

anyone please help me.
thanks

Comment: It show any error on console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return $parent.elems() }"        I'm getting this error.